# Add timestamp in the document while delete API is triggered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add deletedAt timestamp in the document when delete API is triggered instead of removing the document from the collection in MongoDb.

Currently I have defined a delete service which I am using in delete middleware function

```
var delete = function (criteria, callback) { Models.Account.remove(criteria, function(err, resp){
        if(err)
            return callback(err)

        if(resp.result.n === 0) 
            return callback(null, resp);
            callback(err, resp)
    });
};

Services.AccountService.delete(criteria, function (err, resp) {
                if (err) {
                    callbackRoute(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(resp.result);
                    if(resp.result.n === 0) 
                        return callbackRoute(err);
                        callbackRoute(null, {});
                }
            })
```

Can anyone suggest how do I add `deletedAt` timestamp once the `Services.AccountService.delete` function is called instead of deleting the document

Comment: Found the solution and resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to add `deletedAt` and `deleted` keys and perform a soft delete instead.
While performing the delete action, instead of delete, save the collection with `deleted` as true and updated `deletedAt` to the current time.
It will also become easier for you to restore these documents in future by simply updating `deleted` as false.

Comment: Currently I have updated the record with `deletedAt` field which has current time using `Date.now` but can you elaborate more on `deleted as true or false` part? and moreover the records will still be there when I use get API

Comment: It is known as soft delete, when we don't want our record to be permanently deleted we flag it as deleted or not deleted. There is also a module for this functionality https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-delete